# Large capacitors with very high series resonance

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, rf, components

I am trying to build a high frequency amplifier board with the [Mini-Circuits GALI-S66+](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=GALI-S66%2B) InGaP-Darlington RF amplifier. I am trying to resemble the [evaluation board](https://www.minicircuits.com/pcb/WTB-409-S66+_P02.pdf) layout and there they use 2.4nF capacitors to block DC. However I am struggling to find any capacitors that are free of resonances up to 3GHz (as stated necessary in the reference design) and have a large enough capacity. I did find the [muRata ULSC series](https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/capacitor/siliconcapacitors/xbsc_ubsc_bbsc_ulsc), which seems to be free of resonances up to 20 GHz, but those are some *very* costly capacitors (~7€). On the other hand a voltage capability of more than 30V would be beneficial. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What you're missing is that you don't get [owt for nowt](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2013/12/eight-yorkshire-sayings-will-baffle-americans). You either pay serious money for resonance free large capacitors, or you do experiments to find out how to make them. IIRC, we used a very specific 5.6nF multilayer in parallel with a very specific 33pF AVX single layer to get a reasonable ground from 3 MHz to 6 GHz, but it was fun trying out all the different combinations.

Comment: 3GHz is a very hard task at that size capacitance, you would be looking as low-ESL packages to begin with (the wider ones), 

combine that with 30V and that is extremely hard, as it means a larger package, this means higher inductance.

Comment: Okay, so I guess I will use the ULSC capacitors. Thank you for your help.